# error| E0602 local variable 'send_mail' (defined in enclosing scope on line 17) referenced before assignment [pyflakes]

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send a fax, and the way to do that is to send a mail with the function `send_mail`

```
@staff_member_required
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def fax_contract(request, pk=None):
    if request.is_ajax() and pk:
        print("Sending contract for request {}".format(pk))

        try:
            contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Contract.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseNotFound(_('Contract not found'))

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        last_faxed = contract.request.last_faxed_at
        if last_faxed and (now - last_faxed) < settings.LOANWOLF_FAX_GRACE_TIME:
            return JsonResponse({
                'error': True,
                'reload': False,
                'message': _('Please wait at least %(minutes)d minutes to resend the contracts') % {
                    'minutes': settings.LOANWOLF_FAX_GRACE_TIME.seconds // 60},
            })
        else:
            contract.request.last_faxed_at = datetime.datetime.now()
            contract.request.save()
            subject, msg = ('', '')
            try:
                send_mail = send_mail(subject, msg,
                    settings.LOANWOLF_FAX_EMAIL_FROM,
                    settings.LOANWOLF_FAX_EMAIL_TO.format(contract.request.customerprofile.fax),
                    fail_silently=False)
                return send_mail, JsonResponse({'success': True, 'reload': True})
            except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'message': str(e)})
```

Here is the html code where I where the previous method :

```
<div class="alert top white-text {{ object.state|request_state_color }}">
    <i class="material-icons">info</i>
    <a href="{% url "contracts:fax" pk=object.contract.pk %}" class="btn pull-right {{ object.state|request_state_color }} darken-2 btn-process-request" data-turbolinks="false">{%trans "Fax contract" %}</a>
    {% if object.contract.pk %}
    <a href="{% url "contracts:as-pdf" pk=object.contract.pk %}" class="btn pull-right {{ object.state|request_state_color }} darken-2 workflow-bar-btn-spacer" data-turbolinks="false">{%trans "View contract" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
    <strong>{% trans "Once the signature is added to the request documents and approved, the deposit will be scheduled." %}</strong>
</div>
```

Here is the error I add so far :

```
error| E0602 local variable 'send_mail' (defined in enclosing scope on line 17) referenced before assignment [pyflakes]
```

How could I fix such problem?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** Maybe the question is unclear. Please let me know if it is the case.

Here is the the class `btn-process-request` is defined :

```
$('.btn-process-request', node).bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {};
  if ($(this).data('reason')) {
      data.reason = prompt($(this).data('reason'));
      if (!data.reason.length && $(this).data('reason-required')) {
        alert($(this).data('reason-required'));
        return false;
      }
  }
  $.ajax({
    url : $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'POST',
    data : data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.success) {
          if (data.redirect_to) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect_to;
          }
          else if (data.reload) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
      }
      else {
        alert('Error! See console for details :(');
        console.error(textStatus, data);
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the variable `send_mail` to store the result of the function `send_mail` which you imported outside of the function.

You can prevent the warning by using a different variable name to store the result, e.g.

```
result = send_mail(...)
```

You probably don't need to store the result at all, since you have called `send_email` with `fail_silently = False`. You could change the line to simply:

```
send_mail(...)
```

Once you've fixed that, the return statement is going to cause you problems

```
return send_mail, JsonResponse({'success': True, 'reload': True})
```

A Django view should return a response. If you really need the result, then include it in the response.

```
return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'reload': True, 'result': result})
```

Finally, using `except Exception` is usually discouraged in Python. You should try to catch a more specific error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alasdair! I need another answer. I do not have a lot of experience with JsonResponse. Could you tell me if I have to put it `result` in a java script code?  I will put it in my question in a minute.

Comment: The JavaScript does not use `result`, so it doesn't look as if you need it.

Comment: Ok, but how do I need to use `result` here? Does this writing is sufficient? Do I need to add result somewhere so that it send an email?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#send-mail) function returns the number of successfully delivered messages (which can be 0 or 1). It's up to you whether you use that return value in your code, I can't help you decide that.

Comment: The question is simply : How do I use `result` to send my email? In fact, I want when I push the button, it will send an email? Actually, I can't see how the button is related to `send_mail`.

Comment: You send the email by calling `send_mail` in the view, you don't use `result` to send the mail. I've answered your original question, which was about the pyflakes error. Your new questions are not related to that, so I can't help with those.